# How to save the Inventory in a JSONString in C#

Tags: c#, json, list

so today I tried to create a class for my inventory and add items to it. I created 2 classes, one with my inventory: name,amount,slot and one with a list `List<Inventory>`. But it always showed exceptions with this code:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public int slot { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryList
{
    public List<Inventory> invList = new List<Inventory>();
}
```

In my startup code i serialized it,which worked, but i tried to deserialize it, and it threw exceptions.

```
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory() { name = "Burger", amount = 1, slot = 2 };
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(inventory);
```

So first of all, when i try to get the items in the list i get this error:[image: Img1]

What i want: I want a clear JSON-String, which i can deserialize in C#.
i want, that the list looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "name":"cheese",
  "amount":5,
  "slot":1,
 },
 {
  "name":"Bread",
  "amount":2,
  "slot":4,
 },
]
```

Comment: It says there is no implicit conversion from Inventory to InventoryList, consider using `<InventoryList>` instead.

Comment: You are trying to deserialise to an `InventoryList` type but your JSON contains an `Inventory` type. Well, at this point you are in compile time and nothing about your JSON is known, but the compiler knows that `Deserialize<Inventory>` returns `Inventory` and not `InventoryList` hence the error.

Comment: The error is not from deserializtion but from the assignemnt: `InventoryList = Inventory`.

Comment: You serialize one Inventory and deserialize as InventoryList. Wrong Type.

Comment: @Phill but that's the point, you are saying you need to convert, there's no implicit conversion between `Inventory` and `InventoryList`. You'd made an error in your code - you are calling `Deserialize<T>` where `T` is the return type, yet you are expecting `Deserialize<Inventory>` to be assigned to an `InventoryList` .... that doesn't make a whole lotta sense.

Comment: Here: `InventoryList inventoryList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Inventory>(jsonString)` is never going to work no matter what's in the JSON string, it's not what's in the JSON that's the problem, is that if you look at the return type from `Deserialize<T>` it's `T`. Given that you provide `Inventory` as the generic parameter `T` , that would make `Deserialize<Inventory>` which returns `Inventory` not `InventoryList`. Do you not want `inventoryList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InventoryList>`? If you don't understand why this is, read up on generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to serialize/deserialize a LIST of objects. Here's a working example:

```
   Inventory inventory = new Inventory() { name = "cheese", amount = 5, slot = 1 };
        Inventory inventory2 = new Inventory() { name = "Bread", amount = 2, slot = 4 };
        var inventoryList = new List<Inventory>()
        {
            inventory,
            inventory2
        };

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            WriteIndented = true
        };

        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(inventoryList, options);
        Console.Write($"Serialized list {jsonString} {Environment.NewLine}");

        var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Inventory>>(jsonString);
        Console.Write($"Deserialization completed");
```

Result:

[image]

The example above matches the JSON structure that you said you need.
If you still need an object wrapper it should work like this:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory() { name = "cheese", amount = 5, slot = 1 };
        Inventory inventory2 = new Inventory() { name = "Bread", amount = 2, slot = 4 };
        var invList = new List<Inventory>()
        {
            inventory,
            inventory2
        };

        InventoryList inventoryList = new InventoryList() {invList = invList };

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            WriteIndented = true
        };

        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(inventoryList, options);
        Console.Write($"Serialized list {Environment.NewLine} {jsonString} {Environment.NewLine}");

        var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InventoryList>(jsonString);
        Console.Write($"Deserialization completed");
    }
}

public class Inventory
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public int slot { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryList
{
    public List<Inventory> invList { get; set; }
}
```

Note the change for invList. It's a get/set property now.
However, this wrapper will add another layer of curly brackets to your json:

Result:

[image]

Comment: the variable "list" already contains the items in the list (it deserializes the JSON in a list), no need to add them manually. You can check the LIST object after deserialization in debug mode to see the result.

Comment: If you still want the wrapper object - InventoryList, just replace this bit public List<Inventory> invList = new List<Inventory>(); with a normal property public List<Inventory> invList { get; set; } and the serialization/deserialization will work. Note that it will add an extra layer of curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to Deserialize **Inventory** type and assign the result object to **InventoryList**

Answer (score 1):

You can learn from this sample (different json format)

```
        public class Inventory
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int amount { get; set; }
            public int slot { get; set; }
        }

        public class InventoryList
        {
            public List<Inventory> invList { get; set; }
        }



        //SAMPLE 1
        InventoryList lInventory = new InventoryList()
        {
            invList = new List<Inventory>
            {
                new Inventory {name = "cheese", amount = 5, slot = 1 },
                new Inventory {name = "Bread", amount = 2, slot = 4 }
            }
        };


        //it will produce
        //{"invList":[{"name":"cheese","amount":5,"slot":1},{"name":"Bread","amount":2,"slot":4}]}
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(lInventory);

        //How to deserialize
        InventoryList inventoryList = (InventoryList)JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InventoryList>(jsonString);




        //SAMPLE 2
        List<Inventory> invList = new List<Inventory>
            {
                new Inventory {name = "cheese", amount = 5, slot = 1 },
                new Inventory {name = "Bread", amount = 2, slot = 4 }
            };

        //it will produce
        //[{"name":"cheese","amount":5,"slot":1},{"name":"Bread","amount":2,"slot":4}]
        string jsonString2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(invList);

        //How to deserialize
        List<Inventory> inventoryList2 = (List<Inventory>)JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Inventory>>(jsonString2);
```

Comment: here is a tool to convert from JSON to C# easily
https://json2csharp.com/